# Consuming a REST Api

Tags: rest, http, angular

I'm struggling making an REST Api request in Angular 2.

My API itself works, when consuming:

```
http://localhost:8080/tshirts
```

it would return me:

```
[{
  "Id": 1,
  "Title": "honey blanket",
  "PrintTechnique": "sublimation"
}, {
  "Id": 2,
  "Title": "tell your story",
  "PrintTechnique": "screen print"
}]
```

Now, I tried Implementing the request in Angular, inspired by their [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/http/Request-class.html):

```
import {Injectable, Injector} from 'angular2/core';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http, Request, RequestMethod} from 'angular2/http';

@Injectable()
export class TshirtService {
    constructor(public http:Http) {}

    getTshirts() {
        var tshirts = this.http.request(new Request({
            method: RequestMethod.Get,
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/tshirts'            
        }));
        console.log(tshirts);
        return tshirts;
    }        
}
```

The results should be of type `Tshirts[]`, according to my interface:

```
export interface Tshirt {
    Id: number;
    Title: string;
    PrintTechnique: string;
}
```

However, the Console wouldn't print a Tshirt object, instead an `Observable` is being printed:

```
Observable {_isScalar: false}
  _isScalar:false
  _subscribe:(responseObserver)
  __proto__:Object
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

i think the response observable needs to be mapped via something like...

```
this.http.request(...)
.map(response => response.json());
```